# DataGridCell ElementStyle Based on Binding Properties

Tags: vb.net, xaml

How can I create a style for a DataGridCell with DataTriggers linked to properties of the column value.

I am binding my DataGridTextColumn to an object - not just a text/numeric value. The object has properties that I want to use to display a ToolTip, set the color, etc...

I can do this by specifying the column property name within the style as follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Payment Terms" Binding="{Binding PaymentTerms, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource RightDataGridColumnStyle}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding PaymentTerms.ToolTip}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PaymentTerms.HasChanged}" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But I have several columns all looking for the same formatting approach, each based on the data within that column. So I am looking to do this within a Style that can pick up the bound item of that cell.

The PaymentsTerms property is a DataValue class as follows:

```
Public Class DataValue
    Public Property Value As Double
    Public Property HasChanged As Boolean
    Public Property ToolTip As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString()
        Return Value
    End Function
End Class
```